# cordova ios iphone x - fixed element at top 0 does not display at the very top

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, iphone-x

I have a cordova app which shows a header bar at fixed position top 0.

This works everywhere except on the iPhone X.

I have already added the viewport-fit=cover to the viewport meta tag.

I am using Storyboard splash screen.

The app itself seems to use all the available space, since when I scroll content, it scrolls up to the very top of the phone, underneath the fixed header.

I have the same issue with the footer.

I am attaching a screenshot of how the header bar looks.

[image]

When I scroll, content goes behind the header in that white space at top.

Thanks for any help, I have been trying all I have found but nothing solves the problem.

Comment: can you please add your code into snippet?